# Ckeditor does not show content in edit page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for editor in my blog, it works like a charm in post page, but in edit page it can not load content. Here is the way I load ckeditor.

```
<div class="editor-field">
            <textarea id="ckeditor" name="content"></textarea>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.content)

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace('ckeditor', {
            filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
            filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/Statics/Upload/'
        });
        CKFinder.setupCKEditor(null, "@Url.Content("/ckfinder")");
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of your textarea is empty, so there's nothing to edit. You must fill it with the contents that you want to edit.